how can you say the equivalence of "at least zero" in a claim?
a computer implemented method, comprising:
storing a plurality of user profiles, each profile comprising at least zero pictures;

In most social applications, the users have the option to upload pictures, but they are not required to.
To me, it doesn't sound right to say "at least zero" in a claim.
Is there a right way to construct this claim?


Is there a right way to construct this claim?

Yes, it's "storing a plurality of user profiles".
Since "zero or more" is the same thing as "optionally" and non-limiting, just don't mention it at all.
Note this is because we're talking about a method rather than a machine. A machine can optionally accept a certain type of input in a limiting way because there must be mechanism in the machine to accept the input regardless of whether it is provided.
